# Is multiprocessing.Pool not allowed in Airflow task? - AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

Tags: python, multiprocessing, airflow

Our airflow project has a task that queries from BigQuery and uses `Pool` to dump in parallel to local JSON files:

```
def dump_in_parallel(table_name):
    base_query = f"select * from models.{table_name}"
    all_conf_ids = range(1,10)
    n_jobs = 4

    with Pool(n_jobs) as p:
        p.map(partial(dump_conf_id, base_query = base_query), all_conf_ids)

    with open("/tmp/final_output.json", "wb") as f:
        filenames = [f'/tmp/output_file_{i}.json' for i in all_conf_ids]
```

This task was working fine for us in airflow **v1.10**, but is no longer working in **v2.1+**. Section 2.1 here - https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/languages/python/python-multiprocessing/ - mentions *"If you try and create a Pool from within a child worker that was already created with a Pool, you will run into the error: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children"*

Here is the full Airflow error:

```
[2021-08-22 02:11:53,064] {taskinstance.py:1462} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1164, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1282, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1312, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 150, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 161, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/tasks/bigquery.py", line 249, in dump_in_parallel
    with Pool(n_jobs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 119, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 176, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 241, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 110, in start
    'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

If it matters, we run airflow using the **LocalExecutor**. Any idea why this task that uses **Pool** would have been working in airflow v1.10 but no longer in airflow 2.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Airflow 2 uses different processing model under the hood to speed up processing, yet to maintain process-based isolation between running tasks.

That's why it uses `forking` and multiprocessing under the hook to run Tasks, but this also means that if you are using multiprocessing, you will hit the limits of Python multiprocessing that does not allow to chain multi-processing.

I am not 100% sure if it will work but you might try to set `execute_tasks_new_python_interpreter` configuration to True. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#execute-tasks-new-python-interpreter . This setting will cause airflow to start a new Python interpreter when running task instead of forking/using multiprocessing (though I am not 100% sure of the latter). It will work quite a bit slower (up to a few seconds of overhead) though to run your task as the new Python interpreter will have to reinitialize and import all the airflow code before running your task.

If that does not work, then you can lunch your multiprocessing job using PythonVirtualenvOperator - that one will launch a new Python interpreter to run your python code and you should be able to use multiprocessing.

Comment: do you think it is safe to be using `billiard` in lieu of `multiprocessing`? as this seems to be resolving the issue for us

Comment: I have not used billiard myself, except using it through Celery, but the fact that celery workers work with our multiprocessing, is encouraging :). There are a few patches to the billiard vs. original multiprocessing so this is likely that it is safe to use.

Comment: I tried setting "execute_tasks_new_python_interpreter=True" in the airflow.cfg file and the result was that the tasks just did not start running in the DAG...

Answer (score 7):

Replacing the `multiprocessing` library with `billiard` library works, per https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4525. We have no idea why subbing one library in for the other resolves this issue though...

Comment: this worked for me. Airflow: Version: v2.1.3

Comment: Worked for me too in Airflow v2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to joblib python library with lock backend and kill daemonic processes after execution with following [instructions](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/945).